# Oracle Disconneting SQLPlus Session?

Tags: session, oracle11g, sqlplus, disconnected-session

I am using sqlplus to connect to an 10g server and execute an anonymous block which takes a while to run.  For some reason my connection is consistently dropped.  Is there anything I should check in the Oracle configuration that might cause this to happen?

Comment: Do you receive `ORA-03113` error before connection lost?

Comment: No.  I basically see that my connection no longer exists in OEM.  I then ctrl-C out of sqlplus and I get ORA-03114 and ORA-12152 errors.

Comment: And what do you see in SQL*Plus, when OEM shows, that connection no longer exists?

Comment: Nothing, it's just sitting there like it's still running.

Comment: BTW, this is 10g not 11g.

Comment: Are you sure it's the sqlplus session dropping and not your connection (perhaps some system level timeout)? Can you run the sql in a screen /nohup session on the server itself? Is there anything in the alert log? Why are you using ctrl+c? is there nothing in v$session? (I don't know if OEM will be 100% real time). Is cut-off time the same, and what about in v$sql? Have you also tried running a statspack to confirm your session is even executing and it's not been stuck in the anonymous block somewhere?

Comment: I monitored v$session and v$sql and sure enough my session does eventually disappear.  I am trying to run locally now.  BTW, this is on Windows.  I know, I didn't install it.  :)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  I ran my script locally and no timeout.  Something on the network I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to reference another question with SO, but here's another viable scenario...
[Settings of connection timeout for Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029271/settings-of-connection-timeout-for-oracle-database)