# HikariCP: What database level timeouts should be considered to set maxLifetime for Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, connection-pooling, hikaricp

In the documentation for HikariCP, it is mentioned that

> We strongly recommend setting this value, and it should be at least 30 seconds less than any database-level connection timeout.

What are those database-level connection timeouts that should be taken into account for Oracle11.2 database? And how could I find those timeouts (queries to execute)?

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: none (by default).

---

For the record (to include details here in case the link changes), we're talking about property `maxLifetime` of [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP):

> This property controls the maximum lifetime of a connection in the pool. An in-use connection will never be retired, only when it is closed will it then be removed. **We strongly recommend setting this value, and it should be at least 30 seconds less than any database or infrastructure imposed connection time limit.** A value of 0 indicates no maximum lifetime (infinite lifetime), subject of course to the idleTimeout setting. Default: 1800000 (30 minutes)

In my experience, it's a good thing that HikariCP does that. As far as I can tell **by default Oracle does not enforce a max lifetime for connections** (neither on JDBC driver side (1), nor on server side(2)). So in this respect, the "*infrastructure-imposed connection time limit*" is +infinity -- and that was a problem for us, as we did observe issues with long-lived connections. It also means any value is "*at least 30 seconds less*", including the default :)

I *suppose* the connection layer does not do anything about this because it counts on the pool layer above to handle such things. It was not possible with (now deprecated) [implicit connection pool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/conncache.htm), and I don't know if [UCP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/intro.htm#BABHFGCA) (the replacement) does that, but if you use HikariCP you don't use those.

Now, after 30 minutes (usually after many reuses for various purposes) for a given connection, HikariCP closes it and creates a fresh one. That has a very minor cost, and fixed our issues with long-lived connections. We're happy with that default, but still make it configurable just in case (see 2 below).

(1) `OracleDataSource` does not offer any [configuration point](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html#setConnectionProperties(java.util.Properties)) (property or system property) to control that, and I *observed* infinite lifetime.

(2) For server-side limits, see [profile parameter `IDLE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310). Quoting 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967638/6730571):

> Oracle by default will not close a connection due to inactivity. You can configure a profile with an IDLE_TIME to cause Oracle to close inactive connections.

To verify what is the value of `IDLE_TIME` for your user, combining answers from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42022379/6730571):

```
select p.limit
from dba_profiles p, dba_users u
where p.resource_name = 'IDLE_TIME' and p.profile = u.profile and u.username = '...'
;
```

Default value is `UNLIMITED`.

Please note there can be other limits enforced elsewhere (firewall... <sup>yes I've been bitten by that, although most DB systems have a keep-alive mechanism</sup>) that might interfere. So you'd better make it **configurable**, in case such issues are discovered when you deploy your product.

---

On Linux, you can **verify max lifetime of physical connections** by monitoring TCP sockets connected to your database. I've been running script below on my server (from the DB point of view that's the *client* host), it takes 1 argument, the `ip:port` of your oracle node, as it appears in output of `netstat -tan` (or a pattern if you have several nodes).

```
#!/bin/bash
target="$1"
dir=$(mktemp -d)
while sleep 10
do
    echo "------------ "$(date)
    now=$(date +%s)
    netstat -tan | grep " $target " | awk '{print $4}' | cut -f2 -d: | while read port
    do
        file="p_$port"
        [ ! -e $file ] && touch $file
        ftime=$(stat -c %Z "$file")
        echo -e "$port :\t "$(( now - ftime))
    done
done
\rm "$dir"/p_*
\rmdir "$dir"
```

<sub>If you run that and stop it with ctrl-c during `sleep` time, it should exit the loop and clean up the temp directory, but this is not 100% foolproof</sub>

In the results **none of the ports should show a value that exceeds 1800 seconds** (ie 30 minutes), give or take a minute. See example output below, first sample shows 2 sockets above 1800s, they're gone 10s later.

```
------------ Thu Jul 6 16:09:00 CEST 2017
49806 :  1197
49701 :  1569
49772 :  1348
49782 :  1317
49897 :  835
49731 :  1448
49620 :  1830
49700 :  1569
49986 :  523
49722 :  1498
49715 :  1509
49711 :  1539
49629 :  1820
49732 :  1448
50026 :  332
49849 :  1036
49858 :  1016
------------ Thu Jul 6 16:09:10 CEST 2017
49806 :  1207
49701 :  1579
49772 :  1358
49782 :  1327
49897 :  845
49731 :  1458
49700 :  1579
49986 :  533
49722 :  1508
49715 :  1519
49711 :  1549
49732 :  1458
50026 :  342
49849 :  1046
49858 :  1026
```

<sub>You'll need to run the script for more than 30 minutes to see that, because it does not know age of sockets that existed before</sub>

Comment: Ah, good question! On my server I have a "Groovy Shell" (very similar to Jenkins's ["Script Console"](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console)) that I used to inspect the connection objects at runtime. And I could verify that after the time limit Hikari would close them and create fresh ones. I'm not at work so I cannot show exactly how right now (can probably try later if needed), but that was the idea. You could also use `netstat` to check opened TCP sockets connected to your DB, take note of the port number pairs, and verify that no socket survives 30 minutes.

Comment: I've added a recipe to verify that on Linux (hopefully you're using Linux... on a mac it should also work with minimal changes)