# How to check what current IDLE_TIME is set at in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, entitymanager

How can I test what the current setting for the `IDLE_TIME` setting is within my `oracle` database?

Comment: Are you looking for `select * from user_resource_limits  
where resource_name='IDLE_TIME';`?

Comment: "Check" and "test" are not the same thing. Do you want to "check" or to "test"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about IDLE_TIME in the user profiles, then it depends on the username.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROFILE', u.profile)
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username;
```

You can use the ALTER PROFILE statement to change it if you have the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Each profile has an `IDLE_TIME`, so it is not clear what you mean by "**the**" `IDLE_TIME`.

On my system:

```
select *
from   DBA_PROFILES
where  resource_name = 'IDLE_TIME'
;


PROFILE              RESOURCE_NAME   RESOURCE_TYPE   LIMIT           COMMON
-------------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ------
DEFAULT              IDLE_TIME       KERNEL          UNLIMITED       NO
ORA_STIG_PROFILE     IDLE_TIME       KERNEL          15              NO

2 rows selected.
```