# How long is inactive session released if use default profile

Tags: oracle

I'm facing a problem of large inactive sessions on oracle database. I'm going to create a profile to reduce the IDLE_TIME for inactive sessions. However, I'm not sure which is the suitable value. I would like to know how long an inactive session is released / killed if I use default profile?

Thank for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

[DBA Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_idle_time.htm) site suggests setting it to 30 minutes

> You can use profiles to set the connect time and idle time with "alter profile" statements.  Note that idle_time is expressed in minutes and you can express idle_time for 30 minutes by setting idle_time to 30:
>
> ```
> alter profile senior_claim_analyst limit
> connect_time 180000
> sessions_per_user 2
> idle_time 30;
> ```
>
> By setting resource limits like idle_time, you can prevent users from performing operations that will tie up the system, and prevent other users from performing operations. You can use resource limits for security, to ensure that users log off the system, so as not to leave the session connected for long periods of time.
>
> The idle_time parameter limits the maximum time a session can stay connected without doing anything. By reducing the period of time an inactive session stays connected, the probability of that session being a victim of abuse is reduced.

Comment: Thank for your details. I also looked into that article. However, if we are using default profile, the IDLE_TIME is unlimited, and I'm wondering what is the actual value of unlimited IDEL_TIME because server also releases inactive session but we don't know how long it should be

Comment: @ThangMai you can set also max life time of connection in connection pool you are using see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799401/hikaricp-what-database-level-timeouts-should-be-considered-to-set-maxlifetime-f